# how can i remove appendet text from a div?

Tags: jquery, json

hello i am new here and i hope i don`t post in a wrong place
the problem is like this:
i use a .getJson to retrive results from a database.
and the results are appendet to a table [multiple rows] once i click to a img it loads a detailed view of the data into a div(or another table). 
my problem is the following:
i must remove the old content of the detailed div - only the appendTo part -

the code looks somethink like this:

script:

```
$("button.#results").click(
function(){
$.getJSON(dataretrive.php?callback=?&query=1' ,
function(data) {
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
var mindata = "<tr><td class='border'>" +data[i].name+ "</td>";
.... [minimal data]

$(mindata).appendTo("table.#shorttableinfo");

var detailfull = "<tr valign='top' height='25' width='100px'><td> Name: </td><td>" + data[i].name + "</td></tr>"
... [lots of data]

$("img.#editrow" + i ).click(   
function(){
    $(detailfull).appendTo("table.#detailsfull");
});
});
});
});
```

the html:

[html code]

```
&lt;table id="shorttableinfo"&gt; // i need a small table here

&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Name:&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt; [other minimal data] &lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;

&lt;/table&gt;
```

[other html code]

```
&lt;table id="detailsfull"&gt; // i need a small table here

&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Name:&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt; [other minimal data] &lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;

&lt;/table&gt;
```

my problem is that i need the code to be removed before jquery loads the new data into the tablbe with id detailsfull, without removing the first row of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is invalid on `appendTo()`, should be `appendTo("table#shorttableinfo")`

You can remove your rows via

```
$('table#detailsFull tr:gt(0)').remove();
```

The above will remove all rows but the first one out of your `detailsFull` table

Comment: i have decided to use `.empty()` instead of `.remove()` and add the description of the table as variable. I decided this is a simpler way Thank you for quick answer

Answer (score 0):

Give the things you added a specific class:

```
var detailfull = "<tr class=specific-data valign='top' height='25' width='100px'><td> Name: </td><td>" + data[i].name + "</td></tr>"
```

and then clean this out:

```
$('#detailsfull').find('.specific-data').remove();
```